# Javascript: Ignore destructured object parameter if the object is not passed to the function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In my express server I have a function that if a request body is passed to it, it destructures the properties from it as so:

```
export function createProxiedRequestBody({ dateRange, dateFrom, filters },
dateDefault) {
}
```

Its a common function where the object passed to it could be void but is obviously causing errors as such:

`Cannot read property 'dateRange' of null`.

Is there a fancy JavaScript way I can ignore these in the parameters rather than writing an `if` block statement in the function ?

Comment: Read about [default values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You can use destructured parameter with default value assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Destructured_parameter_with_default_value_assignment

```js
function createProxiedRequestBody(
   { dateRange, dateFrom, filters } = {dateRange: null, dateFrom: null, filters: null},
   dateDefault) { 
       console.log('dateRange:' + dateRange);
}

createProxiedRequestBody();  // no error, dateRange === null
createProxiedRequestBody({dateRange: 2});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass default value to parameter which you want to ignore

Something like below

```js
    function foo (x, y = 10) {
        return x + y;
    }
    
    console.log("Ignore y. Sum = "+ foo(10)); //It will ignore y while calling foo function
    console.log("Without ignoring y. Sum = "+ foo(10, 20)); //It assign value to y i.e 20
```